# como cerrar ventana al clickear fuera de un elemento

Tags: javascript, css3

hasta ahora he logrado que se abra la ventana de cada plan con su botÓn y que se cierre si selecciono otro botÓn o clickeando la ventana que se abrió. Lo que no logro implementar es que se cierre cuando hago click fuera de la ventana...

y otro error que no se solucionar es que la ventana se abre en la parte superior del body y no en el lugar donde se encuentra el botón que se selecciona...

paso el codigo para que vean lo que tengo armado. gracias

```js
/*--mostrar y ocultar ventana planes--*/
function ventana(elemento) {
  $(elemento).next('div').toggle();
  $(".ventanas").not($(elemento).next('div')).hide();
  $(document.body).one('click', close);
}

function close() {
  $('.ventanas').next('.openClose').hide();
  $('.ventanas').removeClass('open');

}
```

```css
/*--espacio para planes--*/

section#plan {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 130px;
  /*--130px de 80px cuando esconde footer--*/
}


/*--titulos de cada plan--*/

section#plan #plan1>h3 {
  color: #EC2894;
}

section#plan #plan1>a {
  background: #EC2894;
}

section#plan #plan2>h3 {
  color: #0199f5;
}

section#plan #plan2>a {
  background: #0199f5;
}

section#plan #plan3>h3 {
  color: #b5de0a;
}

section#plan #plan3>a {
  background: #b5de0a;
}


/*--boton "DESDE $.."--*/

section#plan .ampliar a.desde {
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  font-size: .8em;
}

section#plan .ampliar a.desde:hover {
  color: #000;
}

section#plan .ampliar a.desde p:first-child {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}


/*--tarjeta con detalles--*/

section#plan .ampliar .ventanas>* {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

section#plan .ampliar .ventanas {
  display: none;
  z-index: 2100;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 60px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 78%;
  max-height: 65vh;
  left: 11%;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px grey;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: .7rem;
  color: #333;
  text-align: justify;
}

section#plan .ampliar .ventanas.mostrar {
  display: block;
}


/*--titulos planes--*/

section#plan .ampliar .ventanas h3 {
  color: #0199f5;
  font-size: .9em;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <section id="plan">
    <div id="plan1" class="ampliar">
      <h3>PLAN PRIMER VENTANA</h3>
      <a href="#" id="detalles1" class="desde" onClick="ventana(this)">
        <p>DESDE $??? POR MES*</p>
        <p>Clickea para mas detalles</p>
      </a>
      <div id="ventana1" class="ventanas" onClick="ventana(this)">
        <div id="info">
          <h4>VENTANA 1 Te brindamos dos para que elijas la que mejor se adapta a tus necesidades:</h4>
          <h3>PAGOS MENSUALIZADOS</h3>

          <p>El pago de tu web lo podrás realizar mensualizado o trimestral, según tu conveniencia! y dependiendo la complejidad del armado de tu página, o si necesitás que realicemos cambios en las promociones o contenidos con regularidad</p>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="plan2" class="ampliar">
      <h3>PLAN CREZCAMOS</h3>
      <a href="#" id="detalles2" class="desde" onClick="ventana(this)">
        <p>DESDE $??? POR MES*</p>
        <p>Clickea para mas detalles</p>
      </a>
      <div id="ventana2" class="ventanas" onClick="ventana(this)">
        <h4>VENTANA 2 Te brindamos dos para que elijas la que mejor se adapta a tus necesidades:</h4>
        <h3>PAGOS MENSUALIZADOS</h3>

        <p>El pago de tu web lo podrás realizar mensualizado o trimestral, según tu conveniencia! y dependiendo la complejidad del armado de tu página, o si necesitás que realicemos cambios en las promociones o contenidos con regularidad</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="plan3" class="ampliar">
      <h3>PLAN CREZCAMOS</h3>
      <a href="#" id="detalles3" class="desde" onClick="ventana(this)">
        <p>DESDE $??? POR MES*</p>
        <p>Clickea para mas detalles</p>
      </a>
      <div id="ventana3" class="ventanas" onClick="ventana(this)">
        <h4>VENTANA 3  Te brindamos dos para que elijas la que mejor se adapta a tus necesidades:</h4>
        <h3>PAGOS MENSUALIZADOS</h3>

        <p>El pago de tu web lo podrás realizar mensualizado o trimestral, según tu conveniencia! y dependiendo la complejidad del armado de tu página, o si necesitás que realicemos cambios en las promociones o contenidos con regularidad</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que lo tengo, primero, para evitar que al hacer clic, se haga scroll arriba, he puesto e.preventDefault en los clicks para evitar que los eventos propagen. De esta forma se realiza la acción que deseas y el resto se descartan.

Por otro lado, para la posición de la ventana, he puesto como top un calc(50% - 80px) y así se situa en el centro, aunque esto dependerá del alto de la ventana abierta, puedes calcular esto con javascript si cada ventana es distinta.

Ahora, he cambiado los eventos por los clásicos de jQuery ya que me es más cómodo y he hecho un truco para que cuando se abra la ventana, se abra también un div ocupando todo el ancho de la pantalla al que le he colocado otro evento click para cerrar las ventanas. Es un truco que me parece más eficiente que controlar los eventos en body o *. Los divs .desde van por encima gracias al z-index.

Lógicamente, cuando se abre la ventana hago visible el .background. A éste le puedes poner un fondo blanco transparente que creo quedará bien y entonces, jugar con los z-index para esconder el resto de divs .desde aunque entonces pierdes la funcionalidad de abrir otro sin cerrar el anterior.

```js
$(".background").on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".ventanas").hide();
  $(".background").hide();
});

$(".ventanas,.desde").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $($(this)).next('div').toggle();
  $(".ventanas").not($($(this)).next('div')).hide();
  $(".background").show();
});
```

```css
.background {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index:1
}

/*--espacio para planes--*/

section#plan {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 130px;
  /*--130px de 80px cuando esconde footer--*/
}


/*--titulos de cada plan--*/

section#plan #plan1>h3 {
  color: #EC2894;
}

section#plan #plan1>a {
  background: #EC2894;
}

section#plan #plan2>h3 {
  color: #0199f5;
}

section#plan #plan2>a {
  background: #0199f5;
}

section#plan #plan3>h3 {
  color: #b5de0a;
}

section#plan #plan3>a {
  background: #b5de0a;
}


/*--boton "DESDE $.."--*/

section#plan .ampliar a.desde {
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  font-size: .8em;
  z-index:2;
}

section#plan .ampliar a.desde:hover {
  color: #000;
}

section#plan .ampliar a.desde p:first-child {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}


/*--tarjeta con detalles--*/

section#plan .ampliar .ventanas>* {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

section#plan .ampliar .ventanas {
  display: none;
  z-index: 2100;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: calc(50% - 80px);
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 78%;
  max-height: 65vh;
  left: 11%;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px grey;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: .7rem;
  color: #333;
  text-align: justify;
}

section#plan .ampliar .ventanas.mostrar {
  display: block;
}


/*--titulos planes--*/

section#plan .ampliar .ventanas h3 {
  color: #0199f5;
  font-size: .9em;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="background" style="display: none;"></div>
  <section id="plan">
    <div id="plan1" class="ampliar">
      <h3>PLAN PRIMER VENTANA</h3>
      <a href="#" id="detalles1" class="desde">
        <p>DESDE $??? POR MES*</p>
        <p>Clickea para mas detalles</p>
      </a>
      <div id="ventana1" class="ventanas">
        <div id="info">
          <h4>VENTANA 1 Te brindamos dos para que elijas la que mejor se adapta a tus necesidades:</h4>
          <h3>PAGOS MENSUALIZADOS</h3>

          <p>El pago de tu web lo podrás realizar mensualizado o trimestral, según tu conveniencia! y dependiendo la complejidad del armado de tu página, o si necesitás que realicemos cambios en las promociones o contenidos con regularidad</p>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="plan2" class="ampliar">
      <h3>PLAN CREZCAMOS</h3>
      <a href="#" id="detalles2" class="desde">
        <p>DESDE $??? POR MES*</p>
        <p>Clickea para mas detalles</p>
      </a>
      <div id="ventana2" class="ventanas">
        <h4>VENTANA 2 Te brindamos dos para que elijas la que mejor se adapta a tus necesidades:</h4>
        <h3>PAGOS MENSUALIZADOS</h3>

        <p>El pago de tu web lo podrás realizar mensualizado o trimestral, según tu conveniencia! y dependiendo la complejidad del armado de tu página, o si necesitás que realicemos cambios en las promociones o contenidos con regularidad</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="plan3" class="ampliar">
      <h3>PLAN CREZCAMOS</h3>
      <a href="#" id="detalles3" class="desde">
        <p>DESDE $??? POR MES*</p>
        <p>Clickea para mas detalles</p>
      </a>
      <div id="ventana3" class="ventanas">
        <h4>VENTANA 3  Te brindamos dos para que elijas la que mejor se adapta a tus necesidades:</h4>
        <h3>PAGOS MENSUALIZADOS</h3>

        <p>El pago de tu web lo podrás realizar mensualizado o trimestral, según tu conveniencia! y dependiendo la complejidad del armado de tu página, o si necesitás que realicemos cambios en las promociones o contenidos con regularidad</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: espectacular! quedo fantástico mil gracias!

Comment: perdón, hay un fallito, en el evento click de .ventanas y .desde, hago un show del background y por lo tanto, se muestra también cuando se cierra la ventana, no tiene consecuencias porque los .desde están encima con z-index, pero considera crear los eventos .ventanas y .desde por separado quitando el show de .ventanas en el .background.

Comment: ok, gracias por la corrección y tu interés